# strange behaviour of the java

Tags: java

hello I have some question about java, why the following code return strange value?

```
System.out.println("Strange " + (20 * 232792560)/20);
```

why do I recieve `18044195`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `(20 * 232792560)` overflows the range of an `int`, and wraps round the number range several times to become `360883904`.  That is then divided by `20` to give you the result that you see.

If you want the correct result, then you need to do:

```
System.out.println("Strange " + (20 * 232792560L) / 20);
```

(Marking a literal with an `L` means that the constant maths will be done with `long`, rather than with `int`, so this will no longer overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Because `(20 * 232792560)` will perform integer based multiplication and the result is obviously out of `int`'s range, hence the value will be truncated.

Comment: er, yeah. it is not overflowing a lot as I just saw.

Answer (score 0):

Because `20 * 232792560` does not fit in 4 bytes (integer value).

So you got:

```
20 * 232792560 = 360883904; // because of int overflow
360883904 / 20 = 18044195;
```